# Problem with merging two SELECTS (One of them is PIVOT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, pivot

I'm newbie in SQL but I'm trying to do some stuff. I wanted to make some queries in sap sql. I done two.
1st:

```
SELECT 
    OINV.DocEntry, 
    OINV.DocNum AS N'FV', 
    OITM.ItemCode, 
    OITM.ItemName, 
    CAST(T1.Ilosc AS int) AS N'Sum', 
    T1.unitMsr AS N'UoM', 
    T1.[Price Min], 
    T1.Currency AS N'PLN',  
    T1.DocDate AS N'Last'
FROM
    OITM 
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        OINV.CardCode, 
        MAX(OINV.DocDate) AS DocDate, 
        MAX(OINV.DocEntry) AS DocEntry, 
        INV1.ItemCode, 
        SUM(INV1.Quantity) AS Ilosc, 
        INV1.unitMsr, 
        MIN(INV1.Price) AS 'Price Min',  
        INV1.Currency
    FROM OINV inner join INV1 ON OINV.DocEntry = INV1.DocEntry
    WHERE INV1.ItemCode is not null
    GROUP BY OINV.CardCode, INV1.ItemCode, INV1.unitMsr, INV1.Currency
    ) AS T1 ON OITM.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
    INNER JOIN OINV ON OINV.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE T1.CardCode = N'OT-05453' AND T1.ItemCode NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT U_ItemCode FROM [@BP2] WHERE U_CardCode =  N'OT-05453' )
ORDER BY  IIF(OITM.QryGroup1 = 'Y', 'Tak', '') desc, T1.DocDate, ItemCode
```

And 2nd one:

```
SELECT
    P.ItemCode,
    [2017] [2017],
    [2018] [2018],
    [2019] [2019]
FROM
(SELECT 
    INV1.ItemCode, 
    OINV.CardCode as C, 
    INV1.Quantity Volume, 
    year(INV1.[DocDate]) as year

FROM INV1 INNER JOIN OINV ON INV1.docentry = OINV.docentry
WHERE INV1.[docDate] between year(2007) and GETDATE() AND OINV.cardcode = N'OT-05453'
) S

Pivot
(sum([volume]) For year IN ([2017],[2018],[2019])) P
```

Both works correctly.
But I want to merge them. Both selects has same itemcodes. Just wanted to add 2nd query results on the right.
I was trying to use UNION but it wasn't working.
Hope that you will show me right way :)

Comment: You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Okay, so 1st query results are like:
1column-some doc numbers,
2column-more doc ids,
3column-itemcode,
and rest columns are filled by data depends on itemcode

Second query:
1column-itemcode
2-4column-2017,2018,2019 data depends on itemcode.

and I want to add 2nd query results on the right after the first query results.
Itemcodes are same on 1st and 2nd query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of both queries produces some tables. You can put in brackets each query and join them using Itemcode column from both queries. Something like below:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.[2017], t2.[2018], t2.[2019]
FROM
(
SELECT 
    OINV.DocEntry, 
    OINV.DocNum AS N'FV', 
    OITM.ItemCode, 
    OITM.ItemName, 
    CAST(T1.Ilosc AS int) AS N'Sum', 
    T1.unitMsr AS N'UoM', 
    T1.[Price Min], 
    T1.Currency AS N'PLN',  
    T1.DocDate AS N'Last'
FROM
    OITM 
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        OINV.CardCode, 
        MAX(OINV.DocDate) AS DocDate, 
        MAX(OINV.DocEntry) AS DocEntry, 
        INV1.ItemCode, 
        SUM(INV1.Quantity) AS Ilosc, 
        INV1.unitMsr, 
        MIN(INV1.Price) AS 'Price Min',  
        INV1.Currency
    FROM OINV inner join INV1 ON OINV.DocEntry = INV1.DocEntry
    WHERE INV1.ItemCode is not null
    GROUP BY OINV.CardCode, INV1.ItemCode, INV1.unitMsr, INV1.Currency
    ) AS T1 ON OITM.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
    INNER JOIN OINV ON OINV.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE T1.CardCode = N'OT-05453' AND T1.ItemCode NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT U_ItemCode FROM [@BP2] WHERE U_CardCode =  N'OT-05453' )) t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
    P.ItemCode,
    [2017] [2017],
    [2018] [2018],
    [2019] [2019]
FROM
(SELECT 
    INV1.ItemCode, 
    OINV.CardCode as C, 
    INV1.Quantity Volume, 
    year(INV1.[DocDate]) as year

FROM INV1 INNER JOIN OINV ON INV1.docentry = OINV.docentry
WHERE INV1.[docDate] between year(2007) and GETDATE() AND OINV.cardcode = N'OT-05453'
) S

Pivot
(sum([volume]) For year IN ([2017],[2018],[2019])) P) t2

on t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode
```

EDIT: changed wrong alias in select clause

Comment: On the top should be t2.[2019] and now works correctly. I just got confused using INNER JOIN before. I forgot that I have 2 tables, not columns/cells. Thanks for help!